# What is Generics in Typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript

I am totally new to typescript and never into c# or java before.
So even if I read the instruction on official typescript website, I really do not understand the real use of `Generics`.

Here is the simple example of `Generics`. What is the real benefits of doing this below?

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

var output = identity<string>("myString");
```

without Generics, I can just do this way below (or I can use Interfaces to make sure to pass specified arguments.)

```
function identity(arg: any): any  {
    return arg;
}
var output = identity("myString");
```

Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: The first signature means: to accept an argument of some type and return a result of the same type. Your second piece of code does not claim that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just going from your basic example:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

Having a generic *here* enforces a **constraint** between the *argument* (`arg:T`) and the return type `: T{`. This allows the compiler to infer the return type from the argument as shown below:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

let str = identity('foo');
// str is of type `string` because `foo` was a string

str = '123'; // Okay;
str = 123; // Error : Cannot assign number to string
```

Comment: Interesting.. So what is the real benefits of using it?

Comment: You don't need to specify the type explicitly. The compiler can *infer* the type and make sure it follows the generic contraints

Comment: @Ban I have some docs here as well https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html#generics

Answer (score 2):

## Generics in TypeScript

Using generics is a lot safer than using the ***any*** type in such situations.
Let me show you the file contents:

### Without Generics

In the below code randomElem function returning the string from the string array. In randomColor function we are changing the type as number, but it will not produce any error during compile time (or) run time.

```
randomElem(theArray: any): any {
    return theArray[0]; // returning a string.
}

randomColor() {
    let colors: string[] = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green']; // String array
    let randomColor: number = this.randomElem(colors);
}
```

[Without Generics Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy7Ms.png)

### With Generics

But when using the generic function if we are try to change the type then we will get the error while compile itself.

```
  randomElem<T>(theArray: T[]): T {
    return theArray[0];
  }

  randomColor() {
    let colors: string[] = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green']; // String array
    let randomColor: number = this.randomElem(colors); // Produce Error
  }
```

[With Generics Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhi0w.png)

This proves that using generics is a lot safer than using the any type in such situations :).

Answer (score 0):

Without generics, your `var output` can only be typed as `any`.

With generics, the compiler knows that `output` is a `string`.