# waht is the meaning of angular bracket in showed documentation for javascript by vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I use vscode for javascript. For example when I writing a filter on an array vscode shows me this documentation for callback function:

> "< S extends T >(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]
> "

I see <> in typescript code but can't understand concept of it.
what does that angular brackets means?

## EDIT:

why you give me down score?
there are newcomers to javascript like me that using vscode.
they don't see generics, typescript, ..
they see angular brackets in showed documentation by vscode.

Comment: That is indeed TypeScript, *not* just JavaScript. Read http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Comment: It's the type of the thing, e.g., `Array<string>` is an array that contains strings. The `S extends T` then goes into generics where `T` and `S` are parameters for the type and `T` would be matched by something else - the type of `value` in this case. `S extends T` means it's a subclass of `T`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe q is about javascript and vscode. i think types help IDE work better so vscode uses TS syntax to have better relation with programmer. i need  help what is meaning of this document syntax. my q is wrong and must read TS docmentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Generics in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027362/what-is-generics-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular brackets, when placed in certain places, means a [generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027362/what-is-generics-in-typescript).

Typescript is a strongly-typed language which requires the programmers to explicitly define the types of everything in declarations. This introduces lack of flexibility when writing more generic code.

See the function below:

```
function echo(s: string): stirng {
   return s;
}
```

Now, the function is great - it returns what you supply and can work with strings. But it is specific about strings - not generic. You can write the function in a more generic manner like this:

```
function echo<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

This is just the beginning of the idea of generics. [Here](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/typescript-generics-explained-15c6493b510f) is a tutorial which gives you more insight.